# How to use salt.client with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, salt-stack

I'm trying to write a script using 'salt.client' that will run a specified action on a set of hosts.  The documentation at
https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/clients/index.html gives the following example:

```py
>>> import salt.client
>>> local = salt.client.LocalClient()
>>> local.cmd('*', 'cmd.run', ['whoami'])
{'jerry': 'root'}
```

Using that example, the script I've written is:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import salt.client
from multiprocessing import Pool

bootstrap_cmds = []
bootstrap_hosts = ['census-01630c42ebc397280*', 'consul-0090ff8a220eb6ff1*', 'consul-066f3dc733ebf89d8*', 'consul-037c95c90d235f723*']
for host in bootstrap_hosts:
        hostCmd = salt.client.LocalClient().cmd(host, 'cmd.run', ['facter hostname ipaddress'])
        bootstrap_cmds.append(hostCmd)

processes = (bootstrap_cmds)

def start_process(process_start):
    os.system('python {}'.format(process_start))

start_pool = Pool(processes=len(bootstrap_cmds))
start_pool.map(start_process, processes)
```

When I run the script, I get the following response:

```
python: can't open file '{consul-0090ff8a220eb6ff1.node.usge1prod.consul:': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file '{consul-037c95c90d235f723.node.usge1prod.consul:': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file '{consul-066f3dc733ebf89d8.node.usge1prod.consul:': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file '{census-01630c42ebc397280.node.usge1prod.consul:': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The '*' appended to each hostname is to wildcard some funky suffixation that we do with our hostnames in 'consul' -- it works with salt in the command line.  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a workable solution to my problem from a senior DevOps engineer I work with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import salt.client
from multiprocessing import Pool

hosts = [
    "census-01630c42ebc397280*",
    "consul-0090ff8a220eb6ff1*",
    "consul-066f3dc733ebf89d8*",
    "consul-037c95c90d235f723*",
]

def start_process(host):
    salt.client.LocalClient().cmd(host, "cmd.run", ["facter hostname ipaddress"])

start_pool = Pool(processes=len(hosts))
print(start_pool.map(start_process, hosts))
```